# How to monitor activity of all WireGuard clients connected to a server?

Tags: networking, vpn, monitoring, administration, wireguard

I've setup a WireGuard server on a Linux server. Is it possible to monitor stuff like bandwidth, DNS requests, websites visited, etc of all wg clients connected to this server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like with any other network interface, you can observe the wireguard interface with the usual network inspection tools.

Comment: So wg-clients traffics are not encrypted? What are the usual tools for network inspection?

Comment: of course the *traffic* is encrypted – but on the interface that transports the wireguard packets, not on the wireguard interface itself.